# ubuntu 12.04 ibus 1.4.1 behavior

Tags: 12.04, ibus, japanese, korean

Ibus behaves unstable, sometimes it doesn't turn on languages ( I use korean and japanese ), sometimes doesn't detect input. Version 1.4.1, Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: try asking in ibus-user

Answer (score 0):

When my ibus crashes I open a shell and input:

`ibus-daemon -rd`

which replaces the current ibus and run the new one in background.